# Android Room DB - How to open Database directly from file system

Tags: android, android-room

I use Room DB and `createFromFile()` method to open a database file from file system. But Room creates a copy of the designated file rather than opening it directly. Database file will be continuously updated and my application needs to read and display them to the UI, such as using Flow/LiveData. How to open Database directly from file system?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Room only caters for file based databases (i.e. not InMemory databases) that are stored in the databases folder (`data/data/the_package_name/databases/?????`) where ????? is the file name as per the 3rd parameter/value passed to the Room `databaseBuilder` method/function.

- where `the_package_name` is as per the App

If you wanted to access/utilise the database from elsewhere then Room is not an option. You would have to either utilise the **`SQLiteDatabase`'s `openDatabase` or `openOrCreateDatabase` methods** and thus all the Room annotations effectively become redundant, or some other SQLite type library/API. However, the `@Entity` annotated classes could be utilised as the basis/an intermediary for retrieving and storing data.

An alternative approach could be to overwrite the original file, at appropriate times, noting that doing so would have to consider the possibility/complication that **W**rite **A**head **L**ogging may be in affect ( e.g. use the `setJorunalMode` method). Obviously this approach would be relatively complex to implement. Saying that the original file is used once only, when the App is installed or when one of the `fallbackToDestructiveMigration` methods are set to be called and that the criteria for their invocation is met.